# How to read CICD predefined variables

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am really new to Git & GitLab. My aim is to create few CICD jobs which should run when a commit happens on a particular branch. I was going through few topics & videos for the last 2 weeks and come up with yaml file which actually runs now and build some files. My current requirement is to get few parameters like the commited branch name, commited files and then download these files to a remote system. I have gone through the CICD variables and tried to echo these variables to see the values. 
echo `$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME` simply echoes the value `$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME` in the CICD job console.

How can we get this value? Any pointers is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It would be very useful if you would paste here your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file.

Comment: `stages:  
    - build  
Job1:  
    stage: build  
    tags:  
      -  iib-project-dedicated-ruuner  
    script:  
      - echo $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME  
      - call C:\Users\abhi\IBM\IIBT10\GitRepo\cicd.bat`

Comment: Sorry for the misformatting. I am trying now a simple POC to print the variable names. Once its succeded, I will change the code which suits to my build server

Comment: I got my issue. it was a syntax issue and i fixed it. But im getting null value when i echo the value now.

Comment: Please paste your FULL `.gitlab-ci.yml` file. Without it it's hard to look for problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file, it looks like you're in a Windows environment and should be using a different environmental variable.

Eg, `$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME` should in fact be `%CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME%`

```
bash/sh         $variable
windows batch   %variable%
PowerShell      $env:variable
```

See [using CI variables in your job script](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/variables/README.html#using-the-ci-variables-in-your-job-scripts).